# QTableWidgetItem memory issues?

Tags: python, memory, pyqt

I seem to be having some memory issues with my application that I hope could be cleared up!

```
    for x in range(self.record_count):
        for y in range(self.field_count):
            if y in string_columns:
                # pass
                end = string_block.find(struct.pack('B', 0), data[x][y])
                self.table.setItem(x, y, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(string_block[data[x][y]:end].decode(encoding)))
            else:
                # pass
                self.table.setItem(x, y, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(data[x][y])))
```

The lines calling `QTableView`'s `setItem()` are responsible for over 370MB of memory on a 18x49109 table, most of which is just zeros, which seems really ridiculous. I'm processing the data of a 7MB database container file but how is it that pyqt4 is consuming over 30 times that amount to put it into view? Is it memory inefficient or am I possibly doing something wrong, perhaps? I'm only using two classes that are extending PyQt4 - `QMainWindow` and `QTableView`, the latter being the center widget of `QMainWindow`.

Thanks!

Comment: That is a whopping amount of table entries so it doesn't 
really surprise me that Qt is using all that memory to create the GUI elements needed. If memory / performance is your main concern, I would recommend only creating the GUI elements for the currently viewed subset of table entries. Then as you pan, the widget would "pop" the GUI elements from the table that go out of view.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm sorry for taking so long to reply! That sounds like a good idea, although wouldn't that be considerably slow if one scrolls too quickly? Is there anything I can do to minimize PyQt's memory consumption that wouldn't impact performance? Because there's another editor I'm trying to rewrite (since no source), and it's just a kilobyte or two bigger than the file itself. I realize it's probably using a library that's much simpler than PyQt, but I did not imagine a 400 MB diff (without the file in memory and rows/cols set it's at 27MB. I don't mind that.)

Comment: See also [A Model/View Table for Large Datasets](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq07-big-tables.html).